# Evitar que un usuario registre más de una cuenta en un dispositivo [Firebase]

Tags: javascript, html5, firebase, web

Tengo un proyecto en el cual estoy usando Firebase, a los usuarios nuevos se les da una recompensa física y quiero evitar que un dispositivo registre más de una cuenta y así evitar algún descontento y terminar cancelando la recompensa.
Si alguien me puede ayudar solamente dándome el nombre de lo que quiero hacer por que al parecer no fui muy específico en Google y no me da el resultado que busco.